# jQuery UI with Webpack 4

Tags: jquery-ui, webpack

I'm currently migrating Webpack 2 to Webpack 4 and everything runs fine so far. With the except of one little problem: jQuery UI. I'm using the menu widget from jQuery UI by requiring it directly in my dynamically loaded React component with a absolute package name:

```
import Menu from 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/menu';
```

This was working fine with Webpack 2, but it doesn't work anymore with Webpack 4. There are no errors during builttime and not even in the browser. But when I want to use the widget via clickevent, nothing happens. No error, no nothing.

I already read that some people had been facing this issue before, but I haven't found a solution yet. jquery-ui was already on 1.12 so it's the current version (which **could** have been the problem, but no luck here).

I already tried providing any jQuery global varname, with no success:

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "$":"jquery",
    "window.$":"jquery",
    "jQuery":"jquery",
    "window.jQuery":"jquery",
    "jquery":"jquery",
    "window.jquery":"jquery"
  })
```

Comment: webpack provide plugin to expose $?

Comment: Already tried that :( edited my question

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I have a similar issue.

Comment: Nope, I removed the dependency entirely.